# Exception - printStackTrace(Printwriter s) method

Tags: java, exception, printwriter, printstacktrace

I would like to make you think about a tiny problem using the method printStackTrace(PrintWriter s). I need to use it in append mode.

The following example is explaining what I mean:

```
try {

    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("mylog.txt", true)));        
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("I can't open the file mylog.txt");
        }
    }
```

Note that

> new FileWriter("mylog.txt", true);

is the way I open the file (and create it the first time because it doesn't exist) in append mode.

The result is that in the file there is only the last exception and not a series of exceptions. One time it occurred that the method opened the file in which it didn't write anything.
How can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Posting the exception would be helpful for the above.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:554)
 at Test$HandleRequests.run(Test.java:72)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to what [krzyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48382/krzyk) mentioned

Per [OutputStreamWriter.close()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#close()) : Closes the stream, flushing it first. Once the stream has been closed, further write() or flush() invocations will cause an IOException to be thrown. Closing a previously closed stream has no effect.

As mentioned, if you do not call close and this try{}catch is getting fired frequently, you are not flushing content to file.

It should written like

```
try {

} catch (Exception e) {
    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("mylog.txt", true)
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(fw));
        fw.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("I can't open the file mylog.txt");
    }
}
```

A better approach will be

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("mylog.txt", true);
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
try {

} catch (Exception e) {
    try {
        e.printStackTrace(pw);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("I can't open the file mylog.txt");
    }
}finally {
     pw.close();
     fw.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you too much for you explaination :)

Comment: why not use try-with-resources?

Comment: Also, closing PrintWriter also closes FileWritter, so there is no point in doing `fw.close()`

Comment: why not use try-with-resources? - Sure that's also an option and actually a better option.\r
\r

Also, closing PrintWriter also closes FileWritter, so there is no point in doing fw.close() - Actually, it is better to use it otherwise, doing fw.close() will close PrintWriter...so pw.close() is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You should close the created `Writer`s, not closing it might cause the problems you describe.

```
try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("mylog.txt", true))) {
    e.printStackTrace(writer);
}
```

Comment: Can this code be ok??

try {
PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("mylog.txt", true));
e.printStackTrace(w);
w.close;
} catch (...) {
...
}